# angular testing Cannot find name 'ViewChildren'

Tags: angular, unit-testing

when I testing angular component, but console error
angualr version: 8
UI:  ng-zorro-antd 8

[image]

Comment: You need to provide code of the component otherwise it is difficult to identify issue.

Comment: is  .spec.ts file， not .ts file

Comment: That error path shows in the component file itself.

Comment: 哈哈哈哈。 My fault. This is a stupid question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

may be you're missing this

```
import {ViewChildren} from '@angular/core';
```

Comment: I import this in ts file.  but I run command:  ng test --include.   console error

Comment: could you share your component ts file ?